# Embedded Dictionary Output

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why my code produces "mixed results".

Essentially the script gets a ticker id and within that dictionary, it attaches the current price and the currency type e.g USD, GBp etc.

```
tickerDict[result[row]] = {currentPriceData , currencyType[37:]}
```

Essentially the output I would like is Ticker, Price, Currency.
But I noticed when looking at the output in excel the price and currency could be mixed for example:

```
Ticker, Price Currency
ABC,5,USD
DCD,5,EUR
ADF,USD,5
FGA,5,GBP
AFA,GBp,5
```

I fixed the code by using the following Line

```
tickerDict[result[row]] = {currentPriceData : currencyType[37:]}
```

However, just for my better understanding of how code works why was the first method returning results in different orders?

Comment: Sets aren't ordered data structures.

Comment: @jonrsharpe in general yes... however Python 3.6+ dictionaries do have order https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5521670.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek in more recent versions they retain insertion order, they still aren't *semantically* ordered. In this case a tuple or list would be a far better choice even in versions where a set works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is correct. (Collections cannot be ordered using 2 different orders at the same time)